# NullPointer Exception durante cadastro usando o padrão MVC

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, nullpointerexception

Possuo uma aplicação já pronta que foi criada de forma procedural, porém, para fins de aprendizado decidi reprogramá-la utilizando orientação à objetos e o padrão MVC.

Durante o cadastro de uma editora estou recebendo o erro `NullPointerException`.

Utilizando o debug no Eclipse, cheguei a conclusão de que ao clicar no botão de cadastro e acionar o evento, os dados contidos nos `textfield` não estão sendo passados para a classe fachada e as demais classes, porém não consegui localizar o que está causando isso.

Evento de cadastro:

```
//imports   
import livraria.model.editora.Editora;
import livraria.fachada.Fachada;

//variáveis
private Fachada fachada;
private Editora editora;

//Botão salvar
    private JButton getBtn_salvar() {
    if (btn_salvar == null) {
        btn_salvar = new JButton();
        btn_salvar.setText("SALVAR");
        btn_salvar.setLocation(new Point(15, 150));
        btn_salvar.setSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        btn_salvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editora = new Editora();
                editora.setCnpj_editora(textfield_cnpj.getText());
                editora.setNome_editora(textfield_nome.getText());
                editora.setEmail_editora(textfield_email.getText());
                editora.setTelefone_editora(textfield_telefone.getText());
                fachada.insert(editora); //De acordo com o Debug, é nessa linha que ocorre a Exception

            }
        });
    }
    return btn_salvar;
}
```

Classe fachada:

```
package livraria.fachada;

import livraria.controller.autor.AutorRN;
import livraria.model.autor.Autor;
import livraria.controller.editora.EditoraRN;
import livraria.model.editora.Editora;

public class Fachada {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

private AutorRN autorRN;
private EditoraRN editoraRN;

public Fachada() {
    this.autorRN = new AutorRN();
    this.editoraRN = new EditoraRN();
    }

public void insert(Autor autor) {
    this.autorRN.insert(autor);
   }

public void insert(Editora editora) {
    this.editoraRN.insert(editora);
}
}
```

Classe EditoraRN (Controller):

```
package livraria.controller.editora;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import livraria.model.editora.Editora;
import livraria.model.editora.EditoraDAO;

public class EditoraRN {
private EditoraDAO dao;

public EditoraRN() {
    this.dao = new EditoraDAO();
}

public void insert(Editora editora) {
    if (editora != null) {
        dao.insert(editora);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível cadastrar!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Classe Editora(Model):

```
package livraria.model.editora;

public class Editora {

private int cod_editora;
private String cnpj_editora;
private String nome_editora;
private String email_editora;
private String telefone_editora;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

public int getCod_editora() {
    return cod_editora;
   }

public void setCod_editora(int cod_editora) {
    this.cod_editora = cod_editora;
   }

public String getCnpj_editora() {
    return cnpj_editora;
   }

public void setCnpj_editora(String cnpj_editora) {
    this.cnpj_editora = cnpj_editora;
   }

public String getNome_editora() {
    return nome_editora;
   }

public void setNome_editora(String nome_editora) {
    this.nome_editora = nome_editora;
   }

public String getEmail_editora() {
    return email_editora;
   }

public void setEmail_editora(String email_editora) {
    this.email_editora = email_editora;
   }

public String getTelefone_editora() {
    return telefone_editora;
   }

public void setTelefone_editora(String telefone_editora) {
    this.telefone_editora = telefone_editora;
   }
   }
```

Classe EditoraDAO (Model):

```
package livraria.model.editora;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import livraria.conexao.ConexaoMYSQL;

public class EditoraDAO {
private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement stm = null;

public void insert(Editora editora) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO livraria.editora(CNPJ,nome,email,telefone) VALUES(?,?,?,?);";

    try {
        this.connection = new ConexaoMYSQL().getConnection();
        this.stm = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        this.stm.setString(1, editora.getCnpj_editora());
        this.stm.setString(2, editora.getNome_editora());
        this.stm.setString(3, editora.getEmail_editora());
        this.stm.setString(4, editora.getTelefone_editora());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            this.connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Onde está ocorrendo a exceção? Seja específico.

Comment: A Exception ocorre em 'fachada.insert(editora);'

Comment: Onde você está criando a variável `fachada`? Este trecho é o importante.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com os itens que faltavam

Comment: Existe algum lugar onde está inicializando ela? Se não tem em lugar algum, este é o problema, precisa inicializar. Teria que ter um `new Fachada()`, pelo menos.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Mude isto:

```
private Editora editora = new Fachada();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Init.java).

Você precisa inicializar o objeto, não basta declará-lo.

Também pode optar por fazer isto no construtor, como foi feito em outros pontos do código.

Dependo do caso pode ter soluções melhores.

Se não resolver deve ter outros problemas que não dá para perceber só com as informações colocadas.

Comment: Realmente, varri o código novamente e inclui a inicialização diretamente no construtor.